# Freeze Headers in ASP.NET GridView that has custom generated header rows

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have generated custom headers for my ASP.NET grid using the following [article](http://www.technologytoolbox.com/blog/jjameson/archive/2010/04/28/custom-table-headers-with-the-asp-net-gridview-control.aspx).

However, I need to ensure that when users scroll through the grid, the headers are frozen in place. I went through some earlier threads, but none of these serve the purpose since the headers generated are customized...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try my solution. I am not test it is worked, but i think it can support you wanted.

[GridViewScroll with jQuery](http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/)

[image]